# How to interpret composition of Integral operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $Tf(y):=\int_A k_T(x,y)f(x)dx$ and similarly for $S$ with kernel $k_S$.

How do I interpret $STf(y)$?

The book I'm reading states that $k_{ST}(x,z):=\int k_S(y,z)k_T(x,y)dy$. Why is that?

Comment: do you know the definitions involved? if so, this is quite obvious I think (modulo an application of Fubini)...

Comment: @mathworker21 What are the conditions that are satisfied in this case for the Fubini to be applicable in this case?

Comment: okay, you are right to object, but my objection is then that your post isn't well-defined. we would need more information about $k_T$ and the domain of $T$. Similarly with $S$. However, usually with this kinda stuff, people just work formally.

Comment: You're also right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
STf(z) = S(Tf)(z)
&= \int k_S(y,z) \, Tf(y) \, dy \\
&= \int k_S(y,z) \, \left( \int k_T(x,y) \, f(x) \, dx \right) \, dy \\
&= \iint k_S(y,z) \, k_T(x,y) \, f(x) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int \left( \int k_S(y,z) \, k_T(x,y) \, dy \right) f(x) \, dx \\
&=: \int k_{ST}(x,z) \, f(x) \, dx
\end{align}$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. You do an interchange the order of integration, so I assume you use Fubini. What are the conditions that are satisfied for the Fubini to be applicable in this case?

Comment: Fubini is applicable if $k_S, k_T, f$ are all nonnegative or if $\iint | k_S(y,z) \, k_T(x,y) \, f(x) | \, dx \, dy < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help md2 ;)